# Custom links in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I was wondering if someone has had a similar requirement before. What they want is a link that on the main site that would point to a different document contained within a document library every week. So week one it would be "document1.pdf" and week two it would be "document2.pdf" and so on. Is this possible for the navigation that is contained in the left hand side of a sharepoint site? Can a link be tied to a lookup? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some [redirect javascript within the Content Editor webpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery). host it on a page and add a link to the page on the navigation.

This is by far the fastest way to get what you want.

Make sure to follow the advice [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8217/redirection-using-content-editor-webpart) to be able to edit the page once you set the redirect.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very clever. I can't wait to try it out!